# How to add linespace between outcomes from multiple print() commands in a single cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Usually I put multiple `print(***)` in a single jupyter notebook cell.
It's a bit hard to tell the results because there's no linespace between them.
I could put `print()` between each `print(***)` to make a space but I was wondering if there is any better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the characters `\n` in the `print` function. Try the following:

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Number: " + str(i) + "\n")
```

This will create a line break between each `print` outputs.

Comment: In Python 3.7+ you can use an `f` string. Thus `print(f"Number: {str(i)}\n")`

Comment: @joe - assuming you are trying to print a `Pandas DataFrame` followed by a line feed, you will be unable to use the addition operator (``+``), as only like types can be added, and a ``DataFrame`` and a ``str`` are of different types. Try: ``print(df7, '\n')`` and ``print(df7.groupby("Gender").mean(), '\n')`` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to stress an end of line, you could use the `end` parameter of the `print` function:

```py
endl = '\n' + 80*'*' + '\n'
print("Number:", number, end=endl)
```